# How to check if someone else is accessing your Facebook account

Tags: facebook

I want to know who accesses my Facebook profile. How can I get to know this?

Comment: None of the tags you added contain the word Facebook, yet the question is all about Facebook. Please edit your question. Welcome to Web Applications !!

Answer (score 3):

The following page contains all accessible information pertaining to the accesses to your account: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security

Answer (score 3):

Facebook lists a set of security features to track and alert unauthorised access

One such is **Login Notifications**

> We can notify you when your account is accessed from a computer or
>   mobile device that you haven't used before. Choose a notification
>   method below:

https://www.facebook.com/help/413023562082171/